# check if all files exist in a directory otherwise exit python

Tags: python

I am new to python and want to check if list of files exist in a given directory. if any of the files does not exist exit it.

```
def CheckFileexists(dirpath):
  file_list = ['a.txt', 'b.txt', 'c.txt'] // Need to check if all 3 files exist in directory   
  for files in os.walk(dirpath):
    if files:
        print(files , 'has files')
    if not files:
        print(files , 'does not have files')
```

This print all the files but how to compare with file_list that all three files exist , if any of the files does not exists, exit the loop

Comment: Doesn't this need to *use* `file_list` somewhere?

Comment: "No" file_list is just constant list

Comment: You can convert both lists to sets and check if the expected files are a subset of the found files.

Comment: Is their any easier way to do this , if you have to implement this ? Any sample code ?

Comment: How can you "check if list of files exist in a given directory" without *using* that list?

Comment: @MichaelButscher: What "both lists" are you talking about?

Comment: @ScottHunter `file_list` and the file list produced by `os.walk`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this approach helps you:

```
import os


def CheckFileExists(dirpath):
    file_list = ['a.txt', 'b.txt', 'c.txt']

    for file in file_list:
        file_path = os.path.join(dirpath, file)
        if not os.path.exists(file_path):
            print(f"File '{file}' does not exist in directory.")
            return False
    
    print("All files exist in the directory.")
    return True
```

Comment: @Bokambo how else are you going to check if not one by one? :D

Comment: @Bokambo Sry I don't understand what you mean, why would it not work if you have this function and execute it in an if-statement at the beginning of your code?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is easy to read:

```
import os

def FilesExist(dirpath, file_list = ["a.txt", "b.txt", "c.txt"]):
    directory = os.listdir(dirpath)
    for files in file_list:
        if files not in directory:
            return False
    return True
 
print(FilesExist("C:\\Test\\"))
```

Or this is even better:

```
import os

def FilesExist(dirpath, file_list = ["a.txt", "b.txt", "c.txt"]):
    directory = os.listdir(dirpath)
    return all([files in directory for files in file_list])
 
print(FilesExist("C:\\Test\\"))
```

This also leaves you with the option to change default file list easily later.